# Can someone explain why scipy.integrate.quad gives different results for equally long ranges while integrating sin(X)?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically integrate an arbitrary (known when I code) function in my program
using numerical integration methods. I am using Python 2.5.2 along with SciPy's numerical integration package. In order to get a feel for it, i decided to try integrating sin(x) and observed this behavior-

```
>>> from math import pi
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> from math import sin
>>> def integrand(x):
...     return sin(x)
... 
>>> quad(integrand, -pi, pi)
(0.0, 4.3998892617846002e-14)
>>> quad(integrand, 0, 2*pi)
(2.2579473462709165e-16, 4.3998892617846002e-14)
```

I find this behavior odd because -
1. In ordinary integration, integrating over the full cycle gives zero.
2. In numerical integration, this (1) isn't necessarily the case, because you may just be 
   approximating the total area under the curve.

In any case, either assuming 1 is True or assuming 2 is True, I find the behavior to be inconsistent. Either both integrations (-pi to pi and 0 to 2*pi) should return 0.0 (first value in the tuple is the result and the second is the error) or return 2.257...

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Is this really an inconsistency? Can someone also tell me if I am missing something really basic about numerical methods?

In any case, in my final application, I plan to use the above method to find the arc length of a function. If someone has experience in this area, please advise me on the best policy for doing this in Python.

**Edit**
**Note**
I already have the first differential values at all points in the range stored in an array.
Current error is tolerable.
**End note**

I have read Wikipaedia on this. As Dimitry has pointed out, I will be integrating sqrt(1+diff(f(x), x)^2) to get the Arc Length. What I wanted to ask was - is there a better approximation/ Best practice(?) / faster way to do this. If more context is needed, I'll post it separately/ post context here, as you wish.

Comment: Here's a blog post http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/quadratic-bezier-arc-length/ that you might find useful. A link from the blog http://www.algorithmist.net/crlength.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `quad` function is a function from an old Fortran library. It works by judging by the flatness and slope of the function it is integrating how to treat the step size it uses for numerical integration in order to maximize efficiency. What this means is that you may get slightly different answers from one region to the next even if they're analytically the same.

Without a doubt both integrations should return zero. Returning something that is 1/(10 trillion) is pretty close to zero! The slight differences are due to the way `quad` is rolling over `sin` and changing its step sizes. For your planned task, `quad` will be all you need.

EDIT:
For what you're doing I think `quad` is fine. It is fast and pretty accurate. My final statement is use it with confidence unless you find something that really has gone quite awry. If it doesn't return a nonsensical answer then it is probably working just fine. No worries.

Comment: +1. Thanks for explaining about quad as well as pointing out that quad is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is probably machine precision since both answers are effectively zero.

If you want an answer from the horse's mouth I would post this question on the [scipy discussion board](http://www.nabble.com/Scipy-User-f33045.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the discussion board.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that a number O(10^-14) is effectively zero.  What's your tolerance?

It might be that the algorithm underlying quad isn't the best.  You might try another method for integration and see if that improves things.  A 5th order Runge-Kutta can be a very nice general purpose technique.

It could be just the nature of floating point numbers: ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic".](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~dws/grouplinks/floating_point_math.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

This output seems correct to me since you have absolute error estimate here. The integral value of sin(x) is indeed should have value of zero for full period (any interval of 2*pi length) in both ordinary and numeric integration and your results is close to that value.
To evaluate arc length you should calculate integral for sqrt(1+diff(f(x), x)^2) function, where diff(f(x), x) is derivative of f(x). See also [Arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arclength)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do know about the calculating Arc Length. I also read the wikipaedia article. I'll edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't notice that the answer was below the error limit.

Answer (score 3):

```
0.0 == 2.3e-16 (absolute error tolerance 4.4e-14)
```

Both answers are the same and *correct* i.e., zero within the given tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

The difference comes from the fact that sin(x)=-sin(-x) exactly even in finite precision. Whereas finite precision only gives sin(x)~sin(x+2*pi) approximately. Sure it would be nice if quad were smart enough to figure this out, but it really has no way of knowing apriori that the integral over the two intervals you give are equivalent or that the the first is a better result.